# How does a self join table decide what to display when conditions are "identical"

Tags: postgresql, join, self-join

I have a simple chat table. The chat table has a `user_id` column and a `recipient_id` column and a boolean `agrees_to_chat` column.

What I'd like to do, is display the users for which user 1 wants to chat with and whom all other users also want to chat with user 1.

(Note that there will be cases where 1 agrees to chat with 2, but 2 has not gone online to signal a preference yet. Obviously in those cases I don't want a chat to show up.)

Here's what I've come up with so far.

```
SELECT c1.user_id, c1.recipient_id, c2.user_id, c2.recipient_id FROM chats c1, chats c2 
      WHERE c1.recipient_id = c2.user_id 
        AND c1.user_id = c2.recipient_id 
        AND c2.user_id=1 
        AND c2.agrees_to_chat=true 
        AND c1.agrees_to_chat=true
```

For some reason setting `c2.user_id = 1` results in what I want: records where user_id = 1, along with people who have agreed to chat listed in the recipient_id column.

However if I set it to `c1.user_id=1` I get the same results flipped over. Namely, now my results are still people who have agreed to chat, but now the recipient_id = 1 for all results, and the user_id is the different users.

This matters to me because if I want to serve data that shows everyone whose agreed to chat with user 1. But if I decide to reference `recipient_id` in my code, I need to know that won't change...For example, on my computer I noticed that `c2.user_id =1` results in what I want, but in this sql fiddle it seems to be that `c1.user_id=1` gets what I need... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/799a9/2

So what's going on here? Is there something I'm not understanding about my query? Alternatively is there a better query for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: The fiddle shows only 2 columns instead of 4, because your column names are pairwise identical (cf http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4f184/6)  Please use aliases - this will make your result look much more sensible!

Comment: @HansLub that is why I always try to avoid all of these GUI and work with a simple primitive terminal to avoid such problems :)

Comment: @HansLub AHHhhh I can't believe that was my problem...Seems so obvious in hindsight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all 4 columns, since you already know 1st and 4th (and 2nd and 3rd) will be equal. Use `SELECT c2.user_id, c2.recipient_id FROM ...` or `SELECT c1.user_id, c1.recipient_id FROM ...`. In case you actually need several copies of the same column from the self-joined tables, you can give names to them: `SELECT c1.user_id AS user_id1, c1.recipient_id AS recipient_id1, c2.user_id AS user_id2, c2.recipient_id AS recipient_id2 FROM ...`

Comment: I agree with the fact that there is no need for 4 columns. But your SELECT list is not IMHO good either. a user_id and recipient_id is not good what the OP is looking for. It is actually a SELECT t1.user_id, t2.user_id from chats t1, chats t2 WHERE ..., that is, both user ids which is the target. In addition, given the current table structure and the primary key constraint, nothing prevents one from inserting the following row in the table: insert into chats(user_id, recipient_id, agrees_to_chat) values(1, 1, true); that is a user who wants to chat with himself!

Comment: "It is actually a SELECT t1.user_id, t2.user_id from chats t1, chats t2 WHERE ..., that is, both user ids which is the target." Given the conditions, they are equivalent, so I gave the simplest thing which works first.

Comment: Ahhh didn't realize my problem was that I didn't alias the names. Makes sense now. I'll accept your answer. @dariyoosh, thanks for the heads up I'll validate entries so that no one can chat with themselves.